# gulp pipe is not working

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

```html
const gulp = require ('gulp');
const browserSync = require ('browser-sync').create();
const sass = require('gulp-sass');

//Compile Sass and inject into browser
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss','src/scss/*.scss']);
  .pipe(sass())
  .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
  .pipe(browserSync.stream())
  });
```

.pipe is throwing errors and I cant seem to make it work . here's a snapshot of what error it throws

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a semicolon at the end of this line:

```
return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss']);
___________________________________________________________________________ HERE ☝
```

You should remove that so that you call `.pipe` on the [Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) returned by [`gulp.src`](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpsrcglobs-options):

```
return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
```